# lost keyframes from timeline

Tags: animation

I seem to have lost my keyframes from the timeline. They're still there on the dope sheet and dragging the frameline in the timeline still plays animation ok in viewport but I can no longer see the keyframes on the timeline. Everything is selected on the dope sheet and in the timeline view 'show only selected channels is unckecked (although this seems to make no difference anyway). What on earth have I done?
Thnx,
/gary

Comment: Is the object with the animation selected?

Answer (score 1):

I think the object which the keyframes are on was not selected in the viewport.